# How to use KVO observe protocol's property?

Tags: swift, dynamic, protocols, key-value-observing

Xcode shows the error `Only members of classes may be dynamic` when I try to add `dynamic` modifier to protocol's property.
So I tried in another way, add `dynamic` in class instead of in protocol, Gettable properties are must be indicated by writing `{get}`.
This is my code:

#### protocol.swift

```
var myproperty: Int {get}
```

#### class.swift

```
dynamic var myproperty: Int {  
  return otherproperty  
}
```

If I observe `myproperty` in normal way, it will not triggers KVO notifications when `otherproperty` value changed, because `myproperty` value will not change before called or used.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that we can use a little trick to achieve our goal. In `protocol` add a property named `observeKeyPath` Like this:

#### protocol.swift

```
var myproperty: Int {get} 
var observeKeyPath: String {get}
```

#### class.swift

```
dynamic otherproperty: AnyObject!
var myproperty: Int {  
  return otherproperty  
}
var observeKeyPath {
  return "otherproperty"
}
```

#### observe.swift

```
self.addObserver(protocol, 
      forKeyPath: protocol.observeKeyPath, 
         options: .New | .Old, 
         context: nil)
```

Tips: if keyPath using dot syntax like `"object.property"`, make sure that `object` and `property` are all modified by `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you **can** make protocol properties dynamic, just classes/structs.

### EDIT:

One thing you should be able to do is to make your class inherit from NSObject, and then implement willSet and didSet methods that invoke the KVO willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey methods.

I did this with a Swift class before I learned about the Dynamic attribute, and it worked. It should work for a protocol as well, but the burden of making it work is on the class or extension that implements the protocol.